# A holomorphic sequence $u_{j}$ converges weakly to zero implies locally convergence to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, several-complex-variables

I have the following question:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded domain and let $\{u_{j}\}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions in $\Omega$ such that $u_{j}\in L^{2}(\Omega)$, for each $j$. Assume that $u_{j}$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Can we conclude that there exists a subsequece $u_{j_{k}}$ such that $u_{j_{k}}\rightarrow 0$ in $L^{2}_{loc}(\Omega)$?

My attempt: since $\{u_{j}\}$ is bounded and $|u_{j}|^{2}$ is subharmonic, by Hartogs lemma, there exists a subsequence ${u_{j_{k}}}$ and $u\in L^{2}_{loc}$ such that $|u_{j_{k}}|\rightarrow u$ in $L^{2}_{loc}(\Omega)$. But I cannot show that $u=0$.

Comment: Can you please recall what's Hartogs lemma? And your question seems to be unrelated to several complex variables.

Comment: $u_j$ locally uniformly bounded has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence to a holomorphic $u$ by Montel

Comment: @Conrad Thks, this helps to give the answer.

Comment: Happy to be of help